# Programatically fill text box with binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to make a window, serving as an input form, to register a new car to a person (a person can have multiple cars). When I open this window from my main window, I would like to fill some of the input controls automatically. One being the `PersonId`, since this is required to create the new vehicle. I have made an example of my `AddCarWindow` and its view model, leaving out most of the properties, for the sake of keeping it simple.

**View (xaml):**

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModels:AddSalesNotificationViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<TextBox
    x:Name="PersonId"
    Text="{Binding PersonId}
    IsReadOnly="True" />

<DatePicker
    x:Name="CarPurchaseDate"
    SelectedDate="{Binding CarPurchaseDate}" />
```

**ViewModel (C#):**

```
private int _personId;
public int PersonId 
{
    get { return _personId; }
    set
    {
        _personId = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("PersonId");
    }
}

private DateTime _carPurchaseDate;
public DateTime CarPurchaseDate 
{
    get { return _carPurchaseDate; }
    set
    {
        _carPurchaseDate = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("CarPurchaseDate");
    }
}
```

Since my main window do not (and should not) know about the view model, I want to set the `PersondId` via the view/window, right before opening it. Like this:

```
AddCarWindow window = new AddCarWindow();
window.PersonId.Text = SelectedPerson.Id.ToString(); // This does NOT work
window.CarPurchaseDate.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now(); // This works
```

However, while I do get to set the value of the text box, it does not bind to the underlying property in the view model (I am guessing because I set it as a string). It does work for the `CarPurchaseDate` though.

How do I get the value transferred to the view model, without violating the MVVM principles?

Comment: Did u set the `datacontext` to ur view?

Comment: The code you put here for the View, is corresponding to the AddCarWindow ?

Comment: First you have to use datacontext to bind your view to a model: `window.DataContext = MyViewModel` As your viewmodel implements notifypropertychanged, the view will automatically detect changes and fill the form with the values from your model.

Comment: I might have oversimplified it a bit. I do set the data context in the window. I have added it to the example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not setting the `datacontext` So

```
AddCarWindow window = new AddCarWindow();
window.DataContext = new AddCarViewModel 
{
   PersonId = SelectedPerson.Id,
   CarPurchaseDate = DateTime.Now
};
window.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: I am setting the `DataContext` in the xaml in the window. Could this cause the problem? I thought it meant that the data context would exist at that point and that the bindings would work.

Comment: @Noceo you need the set the default here so I suggested like this and the vm is implementing `NotifyPropertyChanged` right.

Comment: Yep, I didn't include the logic for `INotifyPropertyChanged` but it is part of the view model. It also does work if I set the data context manually on window creation, much like you suggest. I have suggested an edit to your post, which is what I ended up using.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some MVVM logic here. If you're correctly binding your view properties to viewmodel properties, you won't have to set the data from the view. You'll just have to set it in the viewmodel, and the data will be modified in the view as well, thanks to the `NotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: You might on to something. I just thought that the better way would be not to let my main window see the view model of the `AddCarWindow`. However, if I do create an instance of the view model and fill the properties (as opposed to letting the window creates its own instance of the view model), then everything works.

Comment: Absolutely, the View should'nt know about the ViewModel at all. 
So maybe I'm missing something. You have your AddCarWindow, and within you have another View, as a UserControl maybe ? Or is the view your talking about the AddCarWindow ?